# XML Obtaining Namespaced node values

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this xml fragment:

```
<ModelList>
               <ProductModel>
                  <CategoryCode>06</CategoryCode>
                  <Definition>
                     <ListProperties xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                        <a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfstringty7Ep6D1>
                           <a:Key>Couleur principale</a:Key>
                           <a:Value>
                              <a:string>Blanc</a:string>
                              <a:string>Noir</a:string>
                              <a:string>Gris</a:string>
                              <a:string>Inox</a:string>
                              <a:string>Rose</a:string>
```

That I am attempting to parse (with simplexml) with this:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays');

        $x = $xml->xpath('//a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfstringty7Ep6D1');
        //var_dump($x);


        foreach($x as $k => $model) {
            $key = (string)$model->Key;
            var_dump($model->Key);
        }
```

That var dump currently returns a whole bunch of

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7823]
```

Which appears to contain the a:Value block. So how do I get the value of the node, not the blasted object tree?

And people think xml is easily parsed.

Comment: What's the desired result? nodeValue/text() as defined by the w3c? The (sub-)xml as string representing the element? Access to child elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you problem is more with SimpleXML as with XML itself. You might want to try DOM.

You can casts results in XPath itself, so the expression will return a scalar value directly.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays');

$items = $xpath->evaluate('//a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfstringty7Ep6D1');

foreach ($items as $item) {
  $key = $xpath->evaluate('string(a:Key)', $item);
  var_dump($key);
}
```

Output:

```
string(18) "Couleur principale"
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the alternative, but unfortunately I'm handling a situation where I'd have to rip up alot of work to replace the xml library, and I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Well, you can use it for only that task. SimpleXML is based on DOM, so it is possible to import an SimpleXMLElement into DOM with `dom_import_simplexml()`: https://eval.in/275718

Answer (score 1):

So I have eventually resolved this problem. For reference (after much trial and error, including a solution based on ThW's answer), this code gets the key property correctly:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays');

        $x = $xml->xpath('//a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfstringty7Ep6D1/a:Key');
        //var_dump($x);


        foreach($x as $k => $model) {

            var_dump((string)$model);
        }
```